# Why is the cell with a length of 0 using the Len() method equal to False when using the IsEmpty() method?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell with 2 spaces as the only contents in the cell, when I use the `len(trim(cell))` method, it returns a length of `0`, but if I use `IsEmpty(trim(cell))` it returns `False`. However, `IsEmpty()` on a blank cell returns a `True`. Why is this the case?

The code I used is:

```
MsgBox (IsEmpty(Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1))))
MsgBox (Len(Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1))))
```

Comment: "IsEmpty returns True if the variable is uninitialized". I think this is the clue. Performing the `Trim` function on the range probably initialises the argument inside `IsEmpty`.

Comment: It is similar to having ="" in a cell. VBA IsEmpty or Excel's =IsBlank function will both return FALSE. Only a true blank (i.e. absolutely empty cell) will return TRUE.

Comment: Thanks I guess `Len(trim(cell))=0` is the way to go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Microsoft [points out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isempty-function), IsEmpty function "Returns a Boolean value indicating whether a variable has been initialized". So obviously a blank cell is considered uninitialized while a string - even an empty one - is initialized.

You could write your own function to test for empty strings:

```
    Function IsStringEmpty(s As String) As Boolean
        IsStringEmpty = Len(s) = 0
    End Function
```

Comment: Thanks I was actually trying to find a way to create a code to not run even when the cell has spaces in them. Because the people using the spreadsheet sometimes presses spaces while doing input work, then makes my code crash because I was using `IsEmpty()`. I guess a simpler way would be to use `Len(Trim(cell)) = 0`